# --enable-precise-memory-info is not working on Mobile Chrome

Tags: appium, selenium-chromedriver, performance-testing, mobile-chrome

Under the:

```
 chrome://flags
```

I didn't find

```
--enable-precise-memory-info
```

Trying to run with:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
```

also had no success, values are rounded.

**Is it even possible?**

Let me know if you need more details on this issue

**Note: it's not about desktop, mobile chrome browse only!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently an Appium 1.7.1 issue.

Follow fix progress here: 
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9838

Comment: was fixed starting from ^1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is with adb

```
adb -s $deviceId shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main argv --args='--enable-precise-memory-info'
```

to obtain device id:

```
adb devices
```

But it wouldn't save flag for the next session, and if you are trying to open it with SeleniumWebDriver probably it should be done with `DesiredCapabilities` through adding `ChromeOptions`... but it's still a question how to do it